# Send all email from noreply@salesforce.com (Not on behalf of user@companydomain.com)

Tags: email, deliverability

We are having deliveribility issues with email sent from SF.  They are all internal notifications from our SF org to our company email.

We use Office 365, user has white listed domain and sender, I have had our IT company white list SF domain and have had them change our SPF records to give SF authority to send on our behalf.  The content is very in-offensive.

But still some users get our internal notifications junked.

Currently the SF notifications are coming though as From: noreply@salesforce.com sent on behalf of user@companydomain.com.

I am aware you can hide the noreply@SF part of the from by ticking or un-ticking the 'Enable Sender ID compliance' setting.

However, I am running out of things to try, I want to force all emails to come from SF with no reference to our company domain or user@companydomain.com.  I think this might be triggering some spoofing rules in 365.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

First set Organization_Wide Email Address - [Organization-Wide Email Addresses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_manage_orgwide_email_addresses.htm&type=5)

Then use setOrgWideEmailAddressId method of [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) in a code where you send an email.